# Calling python multiprocess on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I'm developing a personal app which envolves web scraping stuffs, and inside its folders there's some files that need multiprocessing tools to makes things go more efficient as any other web scraping software. I know that **Windows lacks of some aspects available on Linux such as [fork](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)**, and thus when we want to instanciate a pool process in our program we need to make sure that the process code is enclosed by `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

But something is bothering me. **Here's the scenario** (there are several of them currently on my program). In my file `main` I'm calling `import web_scraping_x`, which contains a multiprocess pool. The question is: How do I protect `my web_scraping_x` code without messing up everything inside of it?

Here's some pseudo-code (for the better good of comprehension):

```
"__main__"

from web_scraping_x import scraping_manager

instructions = ["some list or dict"]

data = scraping_manager(instructions)
```

and

```
   "web_scraping_x"


def escraping_manager(instructions):
    if instructions is True:
        scraping_a(instructios)

def scraping_a(instructions):
    "do a lot of work ur proletariat"
```

I'm trying not to come up with a **solution as bad as the problem on Windows**, even though it may not be possible, such as importing my module with a changed `__name__` ... so any tips humans I really appreciate. If needed, I could show my code, but I think it's just gonna make things more difficulty to share with you.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: How can I help you to help me?